# Should I draw an interface dependency?

Tags: uml

The interface `ISprintsDataModel` indicates that its implemented class will be dependent on the`Sprint` class. Should I draw the `ISprintsDataModel` interface dependency on the`Sprint` class, or is it dependent only on `MySqlSprintsDataModel`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right and the interface is dependent on `Sprint` you shall draw the dependence right on that interface. Currently only the name suggests that they are somehow related. But having the dependency shown it will be absolutely clear that once you change `Sprint` you have to look at the interface as well.